# Eclipse Subversion Share projects operation failed

Tags: eclipse, svn

I recently upgraded Eclipse to the Kepler release and had to re-install all the plugins.
I'm having trouble with the subversion interface. It complains that my client is too old, but I have only Subversion 1.8.1.

I get the message:

> Share project was failed. Unsupported working copy format svn: This
>   client is too old to work with the working copy at
>   '/local/projects/devel' (format 31). You need to get a newer
>   Subversion client. For more details, see
>   http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change

I'm running subversion 1.8.1 (r1503906).
I checked out the /local/projects directory using this client, and running "svn info" on the proj1 directory checks out okay.

Eclipse is not recognizing that the /local/projects directory is administered by svn, so, in the Project Explorer pane, I right-clicked on proj1->Team->Share Project.
I then selected SVN; Use existing repository location; Simple Mode with the proper URL;
Then I get the error message shown above.

In the Team SVN Connector page, my SVN Connector is set to Native JavaHL 1.7.5.
I've also tried it with SVNKit 1.7.9.

Installed:
Subclipse 1.10.1
Subversive SVN Connectors 3.0.1.I20130507-1700
Subversive SVN Team Provider 1.1.0.I20130619-1700

Answer (score 0):

Update to a newer subclipse version (1.10.x), which has JavaHL 1.8.1 integrated. You will need to change the install location, as the new version has a different update site URL.

For details see [Subclipse website](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).